# Show the value of a specific column that has the max count based on its criteria

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am trying to get the cell data of the maximum count of all criteria of column *(summary Table is only for reference counting)*.

1. Get the cell data that has has the highest count under **`Data Value`** column that is based on 2 Columns: **`Master Cluster Column`** and **`Mini Cluster Column`** - Screenshot below

> **Result should be on Highest Data Value (*Mini Cluster*) column:**
>
> Under **`Master Cluster : 10001`** *(highlighted in
> green)*, it has 2 data under **`Mini Cluster`** which is `TEM-101` and
> `TEM-102` , The highest count of **`Master Cluster : 10001`** of
> `TEM-101` is `ABCDEF1` as that's the only data on it (red font), while for `TEM-102` is `101`, since `TEM-102 : 101` data has **3 counts**; while `TEM-102 : ABCDEF1` has only 2 counts (blue font).

[image]

2. Get the cell data that has has the highest count under **`Data Value`**  column based on Master Cluster: - Screenshot below

> **Result should be on Highest Data Value (*Master Cluster*) column:**
>
> Under **`Master Cluster : 10001`** *(highlighted in yellow)*, it has 2 data under **`Data Value`** column which is `ABCDEF1` and
> `101` , The highest count of **`Master Cluster : 10001`** is `ABCDEF1` (red font) as it has 6 counts, while for `101` it has only 3 counts (black font).

[image]

Please see table Below:

---

| Count # | Data Value | Mini Cluster | Master Cluster Value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | ABCDEF1 | TEM-101 | 10001 |
| 2 | ABCDEF1 | TEM-101 | 10001 |
| 3 | ABCDEF1 | TEM-101 | 10001 |
| 4 | ABCDEF1 | TEM-101 | 10001 |
| 5 | ABCDEF1 | TEM-102 | 10001 |
| 6 | ABCDEF1 | TEM-102 | 10001 |
| 7 | 101 | TEM-102 | 10001 |
| 8 | 101 | TEM-102 | 10001 |
| 9 | 101 | TEM-102 | 10001 |
| 10 | JKLMN2 | TEM-201 | Aegis |
| 11 | JKLMN2 | TEM-201 | Aegis |
| 12 | 101 | TEM-201 | Aegis |
| 13 | 101 | TEM-201 | Aegis |
| 14 | 101 | TEM-201 | Aegis |
| 15 | OPQRSTU3 | TEM-301 | Volt |
| 16 | OPQRSTU3 | TEM-301 | Volt |
| 17 | OPQRSTU3 | TEM-301 | Volt |
| 18 | OPQRSTU3 | TEM-301 | Volt |
| 19 | 101 | TEM-301 | Volt |
| 20 | 303 | TEM-301 | Volt |
| 21 | 303 | TEM-301 | Volt |
| 22 | 101 | TEM-401 | Zoom1 |
| 23 | 101 | TEM-401 | Zoom1 |
| 24 | 101 | TEM-401 | Zoom1 |
| 25 | 101 | TEM-401 | Zoom1 |
| 26 | 101 | TEM-401 | Zoom1 |

**Edit 1: Table adjustment**

**Edit 2: Can I also get the formula for showing the 2nd Highest Data.**

Answer (score 0):

Try below formula-

```
=VSTACK({"Mini Cluster","Data Value","Count"},HSTACK(UNIQUE(B2:C27),BYROW(UNIQUE(B2:C27),LAMBDA(x,COUNTIFS(B2:B27,INDEX(x,1,1),C2:C27,INDEX(x,1,2))))))
```

[image]

Comment: quick question @Harun24hr without looking into much details, the question refers to the max counts, but in your formula I see only counts there is no `MAX` criteria. The other thing is that column `D` (**Master Cluster Value**) is not taking into account in your formula I don't fully understand the question, but I guess it should be taken into account.

Comment: Apologies if my question is confusing; But I just need the cell/data of Data Value column that has the highest count per Master Cluster column per Mini Cluster column. On the first screenshot, the highest cell/data count of Data Value Column based on Master Cluster 10001 with **Mini Cluster TEM-101** is *ABCDEF1* and the highest cell/data count of Data Value Column based on Master Cluster 10001 with **Mini Cluster TEM-102** is *101*.

Comment: @Lien0 I am still trying to understand your question, what is the role of the Summary table? what is the expected output, would you provide a sample with the expected output you are looking for? If there are columns that are not relevant for your problem, please remove it. Thanks